# Local component of cuspidal automorphic representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $F$ be a number field and $\mathbb{A}$ its adele ring. $G$ be a classical group and $
\pi$ be a unitary cuspidal automorphic representation of $G(\mathbb{A})$.

Then I am wondering whether there is a known theorem on the local component of $\pi$. For example, the statement I am expecting is $\pi_v$ is supercuspidal, square-integrable, tempered or generic etc for all places $v$.

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: $\pi_v$ can not be supercuspidal for all $v$, in fact, $\pi_v$ is unramified for almost all $v$. Even for $G=\mathrm{GL}(n)$ whether $\pi_v$ is tempered for almost all $v$ is a part of the Generalized Ramanujan Conjecture.

Comment: @SubhajitJana, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Echo, thanks for the nice comment!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me work in the category of $L^2$-automorphic representations.  Assuming your global representation $\pi$ is irreducible, about the only thing you can say about an arbitrary local component $\pi_v$ is that it is an irreducible smooth representation of $G_v$.  For almost all $v$, you can also say $\pi_v$ will be spherical.

I don't know exactly which groups you include in classical groups (unitary groups? non-quasi-split forms?) but if you allow compact groups then the trivial representation is cuspidal, and in positive rank it is locally non-generic everywhere.

For (split) SO(5) you have Saito-Kurokawa lifts, which are locally non-tempered.  Also, many cuspidal representation of SO(5) are not generic everywhere.  See references on Siegel modular forms, SO(5) or GSp(4).

As mentioned in comments, $\pi_v$ can typically only be supercuspidal or discrete series at a finite number of places (e.g., if G is GL($n$) with $n > 1$).

Comment: @paul garrett: that really doesn't sound correct...

Comment: @Kimball, thanks for great answer. I learned much from your answer. By the way, if the condition that $\pi$ is generic os added, then can we say that $\pi_v$’ are generic for all places though we are not sure it is tempered.

Comment: @Satan'sMinion, ah, indeed, my comment from yesterday about Siegel modular forms lacking local Whittaker models was inaccurate and dumb. :)  I don't know what I was imagining I was remembering. :)  Maybe Saito-Kurokawa lifts?  Thanks for making me think more carefully. :)

Comment: @Monty Are you asking if globally generic implies locally generic? The answer to this is yes, by factorization of Whittaker models.

Comment: @Kimball, oh, I see! Thanks for kind reply again!